# How to call on a variable from parent? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

Let's say I have a variable in the actionscript panel on a movieclip

parent_mc:

```
var ispaused:Boolean = false;
```

inside this movieclip is another movieclip with its own actionscript

child_mc:

```
if (!ispaused)
{ gotoAndPlay(1); }
```

How do I call for a variable from the parent when dealing the actionscript inside a child movieclip?

Answer (score 0):

Ahem...

```
if (parent.ispaused) // ...
```

And if this does not work due to compile time type casting:

```
if (parent["ispaused"]) // ...
```

Or you can typecast:

```
if ((parent as ParentClass).ispaused) // ...
```

Comment: correction: these may work, but I was unable to get them to work

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found that this is the proper way to call upon a variable from the parent, quite literally MovieClip(root) is not to change.

```
if ((MovieClip(root).entervariablename))
{ dothisaction; }
```

or to modify the variable value

```
if (thistrigger)
{ (MovieClip(root).entervariablename) = desiredvalue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

On the parent MovieClip Timeline (I suppose that Your code is placed on it) :

```
var isPaused:Boolean=false;
function doSometing():void{
    trace("function doSomething called in parent MovieClip");
}
```

On the child MovieClip Timeline:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
var parentClip:MovieClip = (parent as MovieClip);
var parentPaused:Boolean = parentClip.isPaused;
if (!parentPaused){
    trace("parent clip isPaused = " + parentPaused);
    parentClip.doSometing();
    // Do what you want here
}
```

Output:

parent clip isPaused = false

function doSomething called in parent MovieClip